# Twitter TypeAhead.js Remote Example

Tags: typeahead.js

I am trying to do a remote type ahead feature. How should my remote JSON be structured? In the example below the user has an individual JSON file for every item. Will, I have to create these thousands of files for my data?

https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/tree/gh-pages/data/films/queries

Here is the example:

```
var bestPictures = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  prefetch: '../data/films/post_1960.json',
  remote: {
    url: '../data/films/queries/%QUERY.json',
    wildcard: '%QUERY'
  }
});

$('#remote .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  name: 'best-pictures',
  display: 'value',
  source: bestPictures
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the JSON data in the backend dynamically. [In PHP, e.g., you can use its `json_encode` function to achieve this.](http://samcroft.co.uk/2014/php-json-encode-decode-functions-tutorial/)

If you have difficulties with the route you can change it. Both of the following behave the same (given the right config) – [the second is actually typeaheads default](https://blog.twitter.com/2013/twitter-typeaheadjs-you-autocomplete-me):

```
../data/films/queries/{query}.json
../data/films/queries?q={query}
```

[As for the JSON structure you should check out one of the examples you referenced.](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/gh-pages/data/films/queries/80.json)